# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre estos dos css?

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo este código HTML:

```
  <div class="seccion-inferior contenedor seccion">
      <section class="blog"></section>

      <section class="testimoniales"></section>
  </div>
```

En el tutorial que estaba mirando le daba CSS al `blog` y `testimoniales` de esta manera:

```
.seccion-inferior .blog{
    flex-basis: 60%;
  }

  .seccion-inferior .testimoniales{
    flex-basis:  calc(40% - 2rem);
  }
```

¿Por qué simplemente no lo puso de esta manera?:

```
      .blog{
        flex-basis: 60%;
      }

      .testimoniales{
        flex-basis:  calc(40% - 2rem);
      }
```

Yo con la segunda manera consigo el mismo resultado, no sé si lo puso así por cuestión de claridad, especificidad, buena práctica de programación o para que tenga más peso ese selector.

Comment: En parte es por una buena práctica, si llegase el caso de que tengas otra clase con el mismo nombre que `blog` pero tenga otro tipo de estilo, este se va a pisar con ese segundo que mostrás por la jerarquía global que tiene. En mi experiencia, siempre uso el método 1 para crear los estilos al menos que haga algo global como un `clearfix` que se utiliza en todo el proyecto.

Comment: Podría ser por la especifidad, como bien has dicho, para que la regla tenga más peso. O podría ser porque en tu página podrías tener otros elementos `.blog` y `.testimoniales` y esas reglas solamente las quieres aplicar a los que sean hijos de un elemento `.seccion-inferior`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El primer codigo esta indicando que se apliquen la regla a la clase **.blog y .testimoniales** contenidas dentro de la clase **.seccion-inferior**, con lo que solamente aplicara esa regla a ese grupo de etiquetas.

```
.seccion-inferior .blog{
    flex-basis: 60%;
  }

  .seccion-inferior .testimoniales{
    flex-basis:  calc(40% - 2rem);
  }
```

En Cambio usando el segundo bloque CSS le dices que cualquier etiqueta que contengan la clase **.blog y .testimoniales** se aplique le regla, causando que tanto el contenido en  la clase .seccion-inferior como cualquier otro que tenga esas dos clases tomen la regla.

**Resumiendo:** Es una cuestion de ambito o alcance de la regla del CSS, en la cual quieres que afecte a un grupo especifico o todas las clases etiquetas que contengan esa clase.

Comment: Pero muchísimas gracias amigo,me hizo un gran aporte :)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta a tu pregunta pues... puede ser una o varias razones...

Si nos ponemos a analizar ambos selectores:

```
//Selector 1
.seccion-inferior .blog

//Selector 2    
.blog
```

Si consideramos el selector 1 estamos seleccionando el objeto html con clase `blog` que este dentro de otro con clase `seccion-inferior`. Ojo que el objeto "blog" puede estar en cualquier subnivel del objeto "seccion-inferior", no necesariamente tiene que ser el hijo inmediato de "seccion-inferior"

Para el selector 2 se esta seleccionando cualquier objeto con clase `blog` que este dentro del body y en cualquier subnivel.

Considerando el análisis de ambos selectores pues de aquí en adelante puede ser cualquier razón que se te ocurra acorde a los análisis.

Quizás necesita que el objeto "blog" este dentro de un contenedor con clase "seccion-inferior" porque este objeto le maneja el tamaño o lo visualiza de distintas formas si esta en navegador de escritorio o en móvil

Quizás siemplemente lo hace por costumbre o tendencias que los programadores vamos agarrando a la hora de hacer cualquier trabajo, ser específico con los selectores o lo hace por buenas prácticas, quizás pensó que era necesario hacerlo así pero no lo era, etc.

Todo a partir del análisis de los selectores es mera especulación ya que borraste todo el resto del html dejándonos a la imaginación las posibles razones que pudo haber tenido para hacerlo de esa forma y aunque tuviésemos el html aún así probablemente nos haría falta el css para tener la razón un poco más clara